# How Convert Byte Array To UInt64 In Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, byte, uint64

This is so far what I've done to convert the 8 bytes I received to UInt64:

```
+ (UInt64)convertByteArrayToUInt64:(unsigned char *)bytes ofLength:(NSInteger)length
{
    UInt64 data = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        data = data | ((UInt64) (bytes[i] & 0xff) << (24 - i * 8));
    }

    return data;
}
```

The sender that converts the data to 8 bytes data did it this way:

```
for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
{
    statusdata[i] = (time >> 8*i & 0xff);
}
```

The 8 bytes data data that I received is:

**01 00 00 00 00 00 00 3b**

The output of my method is:

**16777216**

I tried to convert this "16777216" to bytes using calculator and I got:

**01 00 00 00 00 00 00**

which means the 3b was not included in conversion.

But, I tried this code under java and it's working fine. I don't know where the problem is.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UInt64` is 8 bytes, so if you have an 8 byte buffer all you need to do is make a `UInt64` pointer to it and dereference it (as long as the data is in little-endian format on x86 architectures, but I'll get to that in a sec),

So:

```
unsigned char foo[8] = {0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01};

UInt64 *n = (UInt64 *) foo;  // pointer to value 0x0102030405060708

UInt64 nValue = *n;
```

Be aware though the individual byte values on x86 hardware are little-endian, so the least-significant byte goes *first* in the buffer.  Thus if you think about the buffer above as individual base-16 digits, the number will be:

0x0102030405060708  (most significant byte is last in the buffer).

The trick you're looking for though is to simply cast your 8-byte buffer to a `UInt64*` and dereference it.  If you've never seen big-vs.-little endian storage/byte-order before I recommend you go read about it.

p.s. - The sender code is wrong btw, the array index (`i`) needs to run from 0 to 7, so `(i=0;i<8;++i)`, *not* 1-8 or the value of `time` will not be copied correctly.  Incidentally, the sender *is* attempting to copy `time` into `statusdata` in little-endian order (least-significant byte first in the buffer), but again, it's being done wrong.

Also, if the sender code is on Java you need to be careful that the value of `time` isn't actually supposed to be negative.  Java doesn't have unsigned integer values so if `time` is negative and you reconstitute it to a UInt64 it will be a large positive value, which isn't what you'll want.

For the sake of completeness, I'll show you how to reconstitute the data byte-by-byte from the little-endian buffer, but remember, the sender code is wrong and needs to be rewritten to index from zero (and a typecast as shown above would get you there as well):

```
data = 0

for (i=0; i < 8; ++i) {
    data = (data << 8) | bytes[i];  // bytes is already UInt8 * so no need to mask it
}
```